# What should I do if I don't want to set the required attribute for some of my HTML input tags inside a form?

Tags: html, css, forms, css-selectors, required

I have a form which you need to specify the `required` attribute for some inputs in order to work properly.

Here is my code:

```css
:root
{
  background-color: black;
}

form{
  background-color: purple;
}

.Comment-rows {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(161px, 1fr));
  transform: translateY(20px);
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in, transform 300ms ease-in;
}

.Comment-rows .Comment-form {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 60px 0 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  color: yellow;
}

.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox input,
.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox.textarea textarea {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  padding: 0 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: purple;
}

.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox .Comment-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox input:focus+.Comment-text,
.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox input:valid+.Comment-text {
  top: -35px;
  right: -10px;
}

.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox .Comment-Line {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: yellow;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border-radius: 2px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox input:focus~.Comment-Line,
.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox input:valid~.Comment-Line {
  height: 100%;
}

/*textarea*/

.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox.textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox.textarea textarea {
  height: 100%;
  resize: none;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox textarea:focus+.Comment-text,
.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox textarea:valid+.Comment-text {
  top: -35px;
  right: -10px;
}

.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox textarea:focus~.Comment-Line,
.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox textarea:valid~.Comment-Line {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Send button */

.Comment-form-Button{
  margin: 20px;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.Comment-form-Button button{
  padding: 7px 16px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="Comment-rows">
    <div class="Comment-form">
      <div class="Comment-InputBox">
        <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="nope">
        <span class="Comment-text">name</span>
        <span class="Comment-Line"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Comment-form">
      <div class="Comment-InputBox">
        <input type="text" name="lastName">
        <span class="Comment-text">last name</span>
        <span class="Comment-Line"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Comment-rows">
    <div class="Comment-form">
      <div class="Comment-InputBox">
        <input type="email" name="email" required="required" autocomplete="on" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('please enter your email')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
        <span class="Comment-text">email*</span>
        <span class="Comment-Line"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Comment-form">
      <div class="Comment-InputBox">
        <input type="text" name="phoneNumber">
        <span class="Comment-text">phone number</span>
        <span class="Comment-Line"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Comment-rows">
    <div class="Comment-form">
      <div class="Comment-InputBox textarea">
        <textarea required="required" name="message" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('please enter your message')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"></textarea>
        <span class="Comment-text">enter your message*</span>
        <span class="Comment-Line"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Comment-form-Button">
    <button type="submit">
                        <span>Send</span>
                    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

If you pay attention to Snippet result, you'll realize the input fields get some styles when they get focused or when they are valid.

Only two of the input fields have `required` attribute ( email, message). the style has to only apply to `focused` and `valid` inputs ( those which have `required` attribute).

The user doesn't have to enter name, last name and phone number. They're optional. But here, after refreshing the page "name, last name, phone number" input fields will get the focused styles before actually getting focused! They must behave like "email and message" after refreshing the page. It means They shouldn't be focused from the beginning and if you pay attention, they're the only input fields which don't have `required` attribute.

The problem is the `valid` property in my CSS. If I remove it, then the codes won't work properly and if I keep it, then it won't consider "name, last name, phone number" input fields as required ones. So it assumes they are always valid. So they always get the style of a valid field which isn't what I want.

What should I do to my codes without having any detrimental impact on my main style?

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius hi. actually it doesn't matter if i set the value here or not cos the problem was with the style of showing these inputs that hopefully vanown's answer helped. anyway. thank you very much

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius yeah, my bad. i've actually used CSS variables here so you cannot see the purple color as the background. you're right. i apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it only apply `:valid` selector to elements with `required` attribute: `input[required]:valid`

For other fields a trick can be used to apply style if its not empty by adding an empty `placeholder=" "` attribute and the check if it's displayed or not via `:placeholder-shown` selector:

```css
:root
{
  --our-purple-color: purple;
  background-color: black;
}
.Comment-rows {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(161px, 1fr));
/*  opacity: 0;*/
  transform: translateY(20px);
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in, transform 300ms ease-in;
}

.Comment-rows .Comment-form {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 60px 0 10px;
  transition: .5s;
}

.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  color: yellow;
}

.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox input,
.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox.textarea textarea {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  padding: 0 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: var(--our-purple-color);
}

.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox .Comment-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* added */
.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox input:not([required]):not(:placeholder-shown)+.Comment-text,

.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox input:focus+.Comment-text,
/* changed */
.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox input[required]:valid+.Comment-text {
  top: -35px;
  right: -10px;
}

.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox .Comment-Line {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: yellow;
  transition: .5s;
  border-radius: 2px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* added */
.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox input:not([required]):not(:placeholder-shown)~.Comment-Line,

.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox input:focus~.Comment-Line,
/* changed */
.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox input[required]:valid~.Comment-Line {
  height: 100%;
}


/*textarea*/

.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox.textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox.textarea textarea {
  height: 100%;
  resize: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

/* added */
.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox textarea:not([required]):not(:placeholder-shown)+.Comment-text,

.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox textarea:focus+.Comment-text,
/* changed */
.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox textarea[required]:valid+.Comment-text {
  top: -35px;
  left: -10px;
}

/* added */
.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox textarea:not([required]):not(:placeholder-shown)~.Comment-line,

.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox textarea:focus~.Comment-Line,
/* changed */
.Comment-rows .Comment-form .Comment-InputBox textarea[required]:valid~.Comment-Line {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form autocomplete="off">
  <div class="Comment-rows">
    <div class="Comment-form">
      <div class="Comment-InputBox">
        <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="nope" placeholder=" ">
        <span class="Comment-text">name</span>
        <span class="Comment-Line"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Comment-form">
      <div class="Comment-InputBox">
        <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder=" ">
        <span class="Comment-text">last name</span>
        <span class="Comment-Line"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Comment-rows">
    <div class="Comment-form">
      <div class="Comment-InputBox">
        <input type="email" name="email" required="required" autocomplete="on" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
        <span class="Comment-text">email*</span>
        <span class="Comment-Line"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Comment-form">
      <div class="Comment-InputBox">
        <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" placeholder=" ">
        <span class="Comment-text">phone number</span>
        <span class="Comment-Line"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Comment-rows">
    <div class="Comment-form">
      <div class="Comment-InputBox textarea">
        <textarea required="required" name="message" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"></textarea>
        <span class="Comment-text">enter your message*</span>
        <span class="Comment-Line"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Comment-form-Button">
    <button type="submit" disabled>
                        <span>send</span>
                        <div class="liquid"></div>
                    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you very much. you are an angel. i was thinking on this issue for about 2 days. thanks a million!